# preg match in php to get data between html

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following html code

```
<pre 
 class="glossaryProduct">
   data goes here
 </pre>
```

and i need to pull just the "data goes here" between the pre and /pre. Can someone explain how this is done using preg_match?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your simple case the "preg_match" approach would look as below:

```
$content = '<pre 
 class="glossaryProduct">
   data goes here<br>
   and here
 </pre>';

preg_match("/<pre[^>]*?>(.*)<\/pre>/s", $content, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
// now the $result contains the needed data
```